# SQL Query existing table within an existing table results

Tags: mysql, join, reporting-services, datatable, where-clause

SO I'm looking to put together a table resulting from one existing table called edsessioncentredates;

What I want is everyone that is sitting an exam in 2020 November, for the final table to also show me the exams that they sat in the past (which also exists in the original table).

I have a unique Identifier being CandidateCode

only issue being that I have to filter the orignal table by year and session, but then how do I take the results of this (unique Identifier) to then draw the results of previously sat exams to form one table.

what I have been able to produce so far, but doesn't work as it only pulls 2020
and what I need is a result for everyone that sat in 2020, what else did they sit in the past;

```
select distinct es.year, ES.session,SB.CandidateCode
from edsessioncentredates ECD

left Join edsessionbookings SB on SB.sessioncentredateID = ECD.SessioncentredateID
left Join edsessions ES on ES.SessionID = ECD.SessionID
left JOIN EDProgrammes P on P.ID = sb.programmeID

where 
 sb.candidatecode in (select sb.candidatecode  from edsessioncentredates ECD
                        where p.ProgrammeTitle like ('General Certificate%') and ES.Year = '2020' and es.session = 'november')
```

Comment: The last line of your query contains `... and ES.Year = '2020' ... `. Does this explain why you only get records from 2020?

Comment: is possible for you to put the create table and insert scripts with sample data in the question, with desired output ?

Comment: I need the es.year = '2020' as this is the parent parameter basis for which the past data will be based on via the unique identifier 'SB.CandidateCode'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subquery is referencing outside the subquery itself.

As it looks like you are just using the subquery to gets list of candidates, try changing the WHERE clause to something like...

```
WHERE sb.candidatecode in (
                            SELECT DISTINCT b.CandidateCode
                                FROM edsessioncentredates a
                                    JOIN edsessionbookings b ON b.sessioncentredateID = a.SessioncentredateID
                                    JOIN edsessions c ON c.SessionID = a.SessionID
                                    JOIN EDProgrammes d ON d.ID = b.programmeID
                                WHERE d.ProgrammeTitle LIKE ('General Certificate%') 
                                    AND c.Year = '2020' 
                                    AND c.session = 'november'
                                )
```